# Ng update failing; Cannot find module 'node:fs'

Tags: angular, npm

I'm trying to update my angular version from angular 9 to 10.
One of the step is to run 'ng update' command, but it is failing.

Error:
PS C:> ng update
The installed local Angular CLI version is older than the latest stable version.
Installing a temporary version to perform the update.
Installing packages for tooling via npm.
Installed packages for tooling via npm.
Node.js version v13.10.1 detected.
Odd numbered Node.js versions will not enter LTS status and should not be used for production. For more information, please see https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/.
(node:29136) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
**Unknown error: Error: Cannot find module 'node:fs'**
Require stack:

I've tried to install node:fs by doing npm install node:fs, but it does not exist.
I've tried with node-fs, fs but none works.

This is my ng version if it helps:

Package                           Version

---

@angular-devkit/architect         0.901.15

@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.901.15

@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.901.15

@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.901.15

@angular-devkit/core              9.1.15

@angular-devkit/schematics        9.1.15

@angular/cdk                      9.2.4

@angular/cli                      9.1.15

@angular/http                     7.2.16

@angular/material                 9.2.4

@ngtools/webpack                  9.1.15

@schematics/angular               9.1.15

@schematics/update                0.901.15

rxjs                              6.5.5

typescript                        3.8.3

webpack                           4.42.0

Comment: Hi.. Did you find any solution for this issue? I am facing the same issue

Comment: Hi I am also facing the same issue any solution for this ?

Comment: I have this issue here